# viewing pulled project within my project

Tags: git, github

Within my project, I pulled someone else's project. Then at the top of my project directory, I initialized a git repository and pushed it into github. What I see on github is this:

[image]

I am unable to click into the directory and view those files. How do I enable myself to view these files on the github website?

Comment: If you're dealing with submodules you should mention it in the question. The "pulling someone else's project" into yours doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your image is the icon GitHub uses for submodules which are not themselves hosted on GitHub. They are only clickable (and green) when the submodule is a GitHub project.